# Does nodemcu WiFiClientSecure not support for own ngrok domain get request?

Tags: server, ngrok, nodemcu

I tried to make a get request with my own domain made by ngrok but I can't get any feedback. It keeps connection failed. I have tried to make get request to other websites but all works except with my domain name.

Is there any configuration need to do on ngrok?